# Difference in collection view & table view methods

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

UICollectionView has a method indexPathsForVisibleItems that returns array of index paths. Where as UITableView has similar method indexPathsForVisibleRows that also returns array of index paths, buts its an optional. Why is there a difference between 2 similar methods from Apple itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Apple developers aren't perfect and they aren't always consistent.

`UITableView` has been around since iOS 2.0 and someone decided back in 2008 to return `nil` if there were no visible rows.

`UICollectionView` was added years later in iOS 6.0 and someone decided to return an empty array instead of `nil` if there were no visible rows.

Of course this was all in Objective-C. When Swift came along, it meant that `UITableView indexPathsForVisibleRows` needed to be optional since the Objective-C property could be `nil`.

BTW - In macOS, `NSCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems` is a function instead of a property and it is a set, not an array. Again, inconsistent.